# Synonym flugel and flugelhorn tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Can/should [flugel](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flugel) be a synonym of the [flugelhorn](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flugelhorn) tag?

Comment: flügel (with umlaut) is German for grand piano, while flügelhorn is a brass instrument, so they don't have much in common.

Comment: i had no idea that there was another instrument named flugel! i just learned something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we had questions already tagged as such, I would suggest merging them and creating a synonym to [flugelhorn](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flugelhorn), but we currently don't have a `flugel` tag, so I see no reason to create it.